# Is it possible to use i2c accelerator to multiplexer input?

Tags: arduino, i2c, wire, long-distance

I have 10ft long wire cabled i2c 4 buses (for 8 sensors, sensor are not in the same place each has 2 i2c addresses),

I try to use i2c multiplexer [PCA9548A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pca9548a.pdf) with an i2c accelerator [Ltc4311](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4311fa.pdf),

i2c accelerator will be placed in between Arduino and the i2c multiplexer input side, the output side of the multiplexer will connector 4 separate i2c buses where each end has 2 sensors

I cannot use CAN bus, also bigger circuits like i2c extenders

Is there any other way to handle this with a minimum number of components?

What are the other possible issues can occur?

I haven't selected a cable yet.

*edited*

**I2C 400kHz**

Comment: Is the I2C bus operated at 400kHz or 1MHz? What Sensor are you using? Also, it is unsure,if the accelerator is usefull, because it comes before the multiplexer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely use a shielded cable to minimize environmental noise. Also instead of going with higher speed of I2C, lower ones might be less prone to noise.
I know i should extract the use full things from the link I am about to give, but its just to much: https://hackaday.com/2017/02/08/taking-the-leap-off-board-an-introduction-to-i2c-over-long-wires/ In generall it says to use lower ohm resistors, just not to low to not draw too much current. This goes without using a accelerator.